# Generating Fibonacci Sequence and creating subsets for it

Tags: c#, sequence, fibonacci, series, integer-arithmetic

I am trying to generate a  Fibonacci sequence computed by starting with the array [ 0, 1 ] and each subsequent number is computed by adding the two numbers before it.
// E.g.  0, 1, [0 + 1 =] 1, [1 + 1 =] 2, [1 + 2 =] 3, [2 + 3 =] 5, and so on.

Two methods I am trying to implement are below however i am badly stuck in generating a subsets(GenerateSubset(params)). Any help would be really appreciable.

```
    public IEnumerable<long> Generate()
            {
          int i, count, f1 = 0, f2 = 1, f3 = 0;
        Console.Write("Enter the Limit : ");
        count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(f1);
        Console.WriteLine(f2);
        for (i = 0; i <= count; i++)
        {
            f3 = f1 + f2;
            Console.WriteLine(f3);
            f1 = f2;
            f2 = f3;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
  }



public Task<IEnumerable<long>> GenerateSubset(int fromIndex, int toIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

Below is the file containing the test cases which i am trying to pass by implementing those methods.

```
Test cases file:
```

[ drive.google.com/open?id=0B_6Eur5JYu9_MDNfelVKOWswRGs]

Comment: What is `GenerateSubset`? Why does it return a `Task<T>`?

Comment: _"Any help"_ is way too broad, as would be asking for a method to be written completely from scratch. Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried so far, along with a detailed and precise explanation of what _specifically_ you're having trouble with.

Comment: @zerkms : GeneratSubset is a method to generate a subsets within those indexes values provided, which can be used to generate a Fibonacci sequence instead of manually placing inside Generate() method. I am trying to solve this task[ https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_6Eur5JYu9_Y3BhZFdSbkpiWVE] and trying to pass the test cases as in the file attached above.

Comment: @PeterDuniho  I am having trouble with to start with GenerateSubset method. What I am trying to achieve on that method is mentioned just above on comment. Any ideas or what to check on would be helpful as i couldn't find any helpful resource for it.

Comment: Your `Generate` is not complete in the very first place. Then in `GenerateSubset` you simply `.Skip` some numbers, then `.Take` some more numbers

Comment: @zerkms, I tried above code but i do not have much idea of implementing this. Please find the link for both project file and test project file above. And if you could help me in doing this then it will be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a logic for generating a subset of Fibonacci series. here is the logic i write in java. you may convert it into c#.

```
int fibonacci(int x) {
if (x == 0)
    return 0;

if (x == 1)
    return 1;

return fibonacci(x-1)+fibonacci(x-2);
}
```

and second function which generates the subset is:

```
List<Integer> GenerateSubset(int fromIndex, int toIndex) {
    int first=fibonacci(fromIndex);
    int second= fibonacci(fromIndex+1);
    int third;
    List<Integer> result= new ArrayList<Integer>();
    result.add(first);
    result.add(second);
    for(int i= fromIndex+2;i<=toIndex-1;i++) {
      third= first+second;
      result.add(third);
      first=second;
      second=third;
    }

    return result;

  }
```

It returns the list which contain the subset of fibonacci series.

Comment: Thank you for your code. But can please follow the mentioned link to find out the code and test cases. The links are: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_6Eur5JYu9_MDNfelVKOWswRGs       and other link:                                                     
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_6Eur5JYu9_Y3BhZFdSbkpiWVE    Now i want to pass the test cases based on the code. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @Rajesh what is your role in this project? Asking somebody to write code for you does not teach you how to code.